# Ouvir e executar ação

Tags: javascript, html5

Supondo que eu tenha uma tag onde valores são alterados comumente em minha página, exemplo:

```
  <p id="valor"></p>
```

O que tenho que fazer em javascript sem jquery para ficar ouvindo essa mudança o tempo todo e executar uma ação a cada mudança?

Comment: Como o valor de um parágrafo irá mudar constantemente?

Comment: em qualquer ação de clique eu mudo o textContent deste p

Comment: E não pode executar a ação nestes eventos de clique?

Comment: Não, preciso ficar ouvindo essa alteração independente do clique

Comment: existe o evento DOMSubtreeModified que verifica mudança na DOM sem o uso de um Timer, ele vai mudar quando o conteudo do elemento alterar, acho que vai te servir

Comment: você tem algum exemplo dele Hebert?

Comment: Uma boa referencia https://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/02/07/javascript-assistindo-mudancas-no-dom-sem-temporizadores/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correção do comentario, `DOMSubtreeModified` foi depreciado com o novo construtor `MutationObserver()`
pode começar por aqui:

`var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);`

da uma olhada no link do mozila
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver

Refe II: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Ref III: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified